# python tkinter - How can I make ttk Notebook tabs change their order?

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, ttk

Is it possible to do this:

[image]

with `ttk.Notebook` widget?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to bind `B1-Motion` to a function, then use `notebook.index("@x,y")` to get the index of the tab at mouse position. You can then make use of `notebook.insert()` to insert at a particular position.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def reorder(event):
    try:
        index = notebook.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y}")
        notebook.insert(index, child=notebook.select())

    except tk.TclError:
        pass

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

notebook.bind("<B1-Motion>", reorder)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)

frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
frame2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

notebook.add(frame1, text='Stackoverflow')
notebook.add(frame2, text='Github')

root.mainloop()
```

output:

[image]